# Using only the .first() value emitted by BehaviorSubject - Angular & RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Scenario:

I have a service `JobService` , where

```
export class JobService {

    private JobIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');
    constructor() {}

    public setJobId(jobId: string) {
        this.JobIdSubject.next(jobId);
    }

    public getJobId(): Observable<string> {
        return this.JobIdSubject;
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to `subscribe` to the BehaviorSubject in a controller `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.jobSvc.getJobId().subscribe((jobId) => {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        if (jobId === '') {
            console.log('Hello')
        }
    });
}
```

What I observed is that `Hello` is being printed several times and finally I get

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> at ZoneDelegate.handleError (zone.js:393)
>
> at Object.onHandleError (core.js:4651)
>
> at ZoneDelegate.handleError (zone.js:395)
>
> at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:242)
>
> at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (zone.js:258)

I tried using `first` or `take(1)` :

`this.jobSvc.getJobId().first().subscribe((jobId) => {`

I get

> .getJobId(...).first is not a function

Basically, I want to `unsubscribe` the `BehaviorSubject` as soon as I load the component and getting the first value of `Job Id` which is there in it.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md. But you should **fix** the issue, rather than circumvent or ignore it.

Comment: it seems `setJobId` is called too many times somewhere, unsubscribing is not solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
```

It should be:

```
this.jobSvc.getJobId().pipe(first()).subscribe();
```